# How can i change the color of wave effect when I click on a tab of tablayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I'm using `tablayout` and I don't know how to change the color of wave effect when I click on a tab of tablayout. How can i do that ?
Thanks you!!

Default Wave Effect Of Android Studio

[image]

Comment: Try to change your . primaryColor or colorAccent.

Comment: i need to change the color of wave effect when i click, not tabbackground

Comment: I edited my new code

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**tab_color_selector.xml drawable add ripple.xml to state_pressed**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/blue_selected_tab" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

**ripple.xml drawable**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/blue_selected_tab"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"> <!-- ripple effect color -->
       <item android:id="@android:id/background">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@color/blue_selected" /> <!-- background color -->
   </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: no, your answer is change the color of tabbackground not wave effect

Comment: Where should I put the tab_selector.xml?

Comment: `tab_selector.xml` put in `drawble` directory

Comment: And set like `app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"`

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvYmd.jpg)#ripple_bg.xml#

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Set is as tabbackground !

Comment: your answer is change the color of tabbackground not wave effect

Comment: Question is how to change the color of wave effect ! My answer Works . You have to just change the color of ripple effect. I have implemented this

Comment: Check the attached image

Comment: `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/ripple_bg"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>`                                           I don't know why it's not work

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tablayout_id" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:tabBackground="@drawable/ripple_bg"  app:tabMode="fixed" app:tabGravity="fill" ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

Comment: remove android:background="@color/colorPrimary"